# Chrome scrollbars while zooming

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

Chrome shows scrollbars in specific cases when I don't want it to. This seems to be the case when the control or page is zoomed out (<100%), when `overflow: auto` is applied and only at specific (random?) sizes. There is no content in the given element, so there's no reason to show scrollbars at all. Why is this happening and how can I prevent this? I don't want to disable zooming for users.

Sample code:

```html
<textarea style="overflow: auto; height: 100px; width: 500px; zoom: 90%;">
</textarea>
```

Try to resize the textarea, if it doesn't already show the issue.

Example:

[image: Example control with scrollbars]

I'm using Chrome 63.0.3239.132 (64bit) right now.

Comment: About the close vote: anything missing from the verifiable example, or not reproducible?

Comment: I can reproduce the problem in v63, but not in the v65 Canary. So I think it's a bug that has since been solved.

Comment: WRT the close vote: I think people just dislike JSFiddle, especially when it's not needed. You might need JSFiddle to demonstrate SCSS problems or the like, but not in this case.

Comment: @MrLister Agreed, thanks for the feedback. I've inlined the code as a snippet.

Comment: Seems to be related to https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=799412

Comment: Ah, nice find. If that turns out to be the answer, you can post an answer here.

Answer (score 0):

zoom is not standard, use `transform: scale` instead

```html
<style>
.txtArea{
    overflow:auto;
    height:100px;
    width:500px;
    -moz-transform: scale(0.9);
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.9);
    -o-transform: scale(0.9);
    transform: scale(0.9);
}
</style>
<textarea class="txtArea">
</textarea>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. `zoom`, in this case, was used to illustrate browser zooming. I'm not trying to scale the element.

Comment: in that case if the element get scroll bars it's probably because the zooming changes the size of the element, try to capture the zoom event and reset the size of your element